# Angular Material Grid Controlling the order of tiles

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material, grid-layout

How can I dynamically change the order of tiles in an angular material grid? I'm using the grid to create dynamic layouts and we've a feature to drag and drop fields. Is there any attribute available like `flex-order` and by applying the order of the tile inside the grid can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

There is an ["order-property"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#order-property) that you can use as:

```
.wrapper {
   width: 600px;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 100px);
   grid-gap: 10px;
}

.box1 {
   order: 3;
}
```

Here's the example [codepen](http://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/OVKPoy).